# How to find the integer solution for $6x + 25 = 7y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers

When I type this equation ($6x + 25 = 7y$) into WolframAlpha, it is able to tell me that the integer solution for this equation is:

> $x = 7n + 4$, $y = 6n + 7$, where n in the set of all integers

How can I arrive at this solution on my own?

Comment: **Hint** $\ (7 - 6 = 1)\ $ times $25.\ $ Generally use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to get the Bezout identity $\, ja + kb = c\,$ for $\,\gcd(a,,b) = c\,$ then scale that as need be.

Comment: Plug in the solution and see what the result is. Can you now do the backwards operation?

Comment: @PeterChikov what if I don't know the solution?

Comment: And see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2304309/242) for the form of the *general* solution (= particular + homogeneous solution)

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque I will take a look at these!

Comment: If you plug in the solution you get 42n + 49 = 42n + 49. Working backwards you know that you have to have n's cancel out. So x = 7n + a and y = 6n + b. Plug that in and figure out what a's and b's have to be.

Comment: This article was helpful: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51595.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $6\mid 6y-24$ and $6\mid 7y-25$ we have $$6\mid (7y-25)-(6y-24)=y-1$$

Thus $y-1 = 6t$ for some integer $t$, so $\boxed{y= 6t+1}$ and pluging in $6x+25=7y$ we get: $$6x+25 =42t+7\implies \boxed{x= 7t-3}$$

---

It looks on first sight that I got different solution, but that is not true.

Puting $n=t-1$ we get $$ y=6t+1= 6(t-1)+7=6n+7$$ and $$x= 7(t-1)+4=7n+4$$

Comment: What does the vertical pipe symbol mean? Is there an article I can read to learn about that?

Comment: $a\mid b$ means $a$ divide $b$, so $3\mid 12$ is true, while $8\mid 4$ is not.

Comment: The only potential problem I might see with this is that I don't think $7y - 25$ will always be divisible by $6$. For example, when $y = 0$.

Comment: Is 0 of form 6n+7?

Comment: Ahh I see now. My bad. Please disregard my last comment.